# how to set value to 0 if sql query is invalid or finds no results?

Tags: drupal

I use the following code to prefil a field with an amount from a database.

```
$amount = db_result(db_query('SELECT amount FROM {table} WHERE nid = %d', $fid));

$node->edit_user_fid = $amount;
```

If the query doesnt find anything it just shows empty. How can I get the value to be 0 if theres no results?

Comment: one note: this looks like the drupal api, if it is, finding no results will not "show empty" it will return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$node->edit_user_fid = ($amount) ? $amount : 0;
```

Or also writeable as

```
if (!$amount) {
    $node->edit_user_fid = 0;
}
```

or if you're sure that $amout is numerical (and it should be), use

```
$node->edit_user_fid = intval($node->edit_user_fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

if amount is an int, you can use intval() or an (int) cast so you will always get a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

`db_result()` returns `FALSE` when it cannot find any table row matching the query being executed. Just cast the returned value to an integer.

```
$node->edit_user_fid = (int) db_result(db_query('SELECT amount FROM {table} WHERE nid = %d', $fid));
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

-.-  you can use ===false or ===0 to teste if it's zero or false (test type and value)
no need to test false and reset to 0 or to set type of variable